# Cakephp 2x Upload image

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.9

I'm trying to upload an image to my local folder

> webroot/img/

and save the image name to database. Everything seems working fine but the image is not saving to the path

**here's my view**

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create(null,['url' => ['controller' => 'users', action' => 'update_image'],
array('enctype'=>'multipart/form-data')]); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('User.id') ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->file('Profile.picture',['type'=>'file']) ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->end('submit') ?>
```

**My controller**

```
public function update_image(){

    $id = $this->Auth->user('id'); 
    $this->Profile->id = $id; 
    $this->set('profile', $this->User->findById($id)); 

    if ($this->request->is(array('post','put'))) {
    $frmData = $this->request->data;

        //Path to store upload image
        $target = "/teamjob_back/img/../img/".basename($frmData['Profile']['picture']);

        //Get the data from form
        $image = $frmData['Profile']['picture'];

        //save data to database
        $this->Profile->save($this->request->data);

        //Image store to the img folder
        if (move_uploaded_file($image['tmp_name']['name'], $target)) {
            echo "Image successfull";
        }
    }
}
```

**And the code**

```
$image['tmp_name']['name']
```

gives me an Illegal string offset error.

> **EDITED**
>   **This code works on the controller**

```
if ($this->request->is('post')) { 
        $frmData = $this->request->data;  
        $tmp = $frmData['picture']['tmp_name']; 
        $hash = rand();
        $date = date("Ymd");
        $image = $date.$hash."-".$frmData['picture']['name'];
        $target = WWW_ROOT.'img'.DS.'uploads'.DS; 

        $target = $target.basename($image); 
        if (move_uploaded_file($tmp, $target)) {
            echo "Successfully moved"; 
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Error";
        }
    }
```

Comment: `<?= $this->Form->create(NULL, ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']) ?>` have you add enctype when creating the form?

Comment: `<form action="/teamjob_back/users/picture" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="UserPictureForm" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">`

Comment: that code works

Answer (score 0):

First add

```
['type' => 'file']
```

as an option to your file instead of trying to send enctype.

Second `$image` is a `$this->request->data['Profile']['picture']` so you can't do `['tmp_name']` and `['name']` together ... debug(`$this->request->data['Profile']['picture']` and you'll see that you could have

```
$image['tmp_name']
```

or

```
$image['name']
```

but not both together.

Probably more but those are good starts.

Comment: i did this `move_uploaded_file($image['name'], $target)` on my controller and also `<?php echo $this->Form->create(null,['url' => ['controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'update_image'],
array('type'=>'file')]); ?>` to my view but still nothing happens can you instruct me more thank you sir

Comment: that shouldn't have worked ... you'd need the $image['tmp_name'] to the target as that would move say /tmp/image.jdkkd.jpeg to the target .... and then you'd want to save that into the db too

Comment: you might consider using something like Proffer.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to remove "type => file" becuase you already use Form helper "file" function , if we are use "Form->input" then we use 'type=>file'

```
    e.g. $this->Form->input('email', array('type' => 'email'));
$this->Form->file('Profile.picture')
```

check your target path have write permission, pr($image) then you get proper array format of $image['temp_name] or $image[0]['temp_name] etc.
and put your temp_name in move_uploaded_file function

```
e.g. move_uploaded_file(your temp_name)
```

[Form Helper](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html)

Answer (score 0):

make sure to include enctype when you create the form uploading file

```
 <?= $this->Form->create(NULL, ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']) ?>
```